# Create a mechanism in php to find if the website is the same even if it has http, https, or neither

Tags: php, http, https, protocols

I want to create a system in php which shows if the website is same even if the protocols are there or not:

**Example:**

```
www.facebook.com
facebook.com
http://facebook.com
https://facebook.com
http://www.facebook.com
https://www.facebook.com
```

All these are the same website, just written differently. The main component is "facebook.com", others are protocols used.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not fluent in PHP, but there probably is a function to parse urls our of the box. You might have an issue with the missing scheme (http/https)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make use of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In your case, you need a regex to identify the second-level domain (SLD). The following expression covers your case, but you might want to extend or refine the list of top-level domains (TLD) (`.com`, `.org`, `.net`, etc) to make it more generic:

```
https?:\/\/(.*\.)?(.*)(.com|.org|.net)
```

This expression will return 3 groups:

- Group 1: subdomains
- Group 2: second-level domain
- Group 3: top-level domain

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/BMolne/1) you can try the mentioned regex.
If you want to know more on how to use regex in PHP, take a look at [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Answer (score 0):

It could be good solution for your problem:

```
function isMatches(...$urls): bool
{
    if(count($urls) <= 1) {
        return true;
    }

    $pattern = '/^(http)(s)?(:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)$/';
    $url = preg_replace($pattern, '$5', $urls[0]);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
        if($url !== preg_replace($pattern, '$5', $urls[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And test:

```
$result = isMatches(
    'http://facebook.com',
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    'https://facebook.com',
    'https://www.facebook.com'
); // true

$result = isMatches(
    'http://facebook.com2',
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    'https://facebook.com',
    'https://www.facebook.com'
); // false
```

Comment: It doesn't match for www.facebook.com

Comment: Update regular expression to $pattern = '/^(https?:\/\/)?(:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)$/'; to include www.facebook.com only.